# Play video in collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add video autoplay functionality in my application.

What I have to implement?

There is `newsfeed` type screen, in which, I have used `collectionView` inside `tableView` to display different types of cells which are video, image, text.

I want to play multiple videos simultaneously in `collectionView` cell.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: use AVPlayer object to play your video in the cell.

Comment: Play video, when you cell is about to visible and stop and release media file when it is going to disapear. Just try it.. if you face any issue.. we always welcome your query.. Thanks